# OpenCV's waitKey() alternative in IPython Notebook

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to show images with cv2 library in my Jupiter Notebook with `cv2.imshow(img)` and it shows as expected, but I can not use or don't know how to use `cv2.waitKey(0)`, hence the cell will not stop executing.

`cv2.waitKey(0)` works in script, but not in Notebook.

Here's a snippet:

```
cv2.imshow('Image', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How do I stop executing cell without restarting the whole kernel?

Comment: does for example `cv2.waitKey(5000)` work as expected and stops executing after 5000 milliseconds?

Comment: @Micka, no. If I put any number other than 0, it shows only the window where the image should be displayed and then this window becomes unresponsive.

Comment: according to http://txt.arboreus.com/2012/07/11/highgui-opencv-window-from-ipython.html you have to use `cv2.startWindowThread()` before GUI calls

Comment: @Micka, funny thing: I came across this before and tried to use it but it didn't work for some reason. Now I tried again and it worked. Thanks for making me try it again! :)

Comment: @primoz You probably did what I did and forgot to restart your kernel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, thanks to @Micka, here's the solution:

You must write `cv2.startWindowThread()` first, explained [here](http://txt.arboreus.com/2012/07/11/highgui-opencv-window-from-ipython.html).

Comment: in the same cell?  that link does not specify.

Comment: @mLstudent33 it does not matter, but you should execute it before calling any other `cv2` methods.

Comment: this does not work for me, every time it crashes the kernel and Jupyter Notebook shows a red Dead kernel.

Comment: Super! Have been looking for this for a while now. Added a working code below, let's merge? ;)

Comment: `startWindowThread` only works on some systems because it is only implemented for some GUI toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from `primoz` very useful. Here is a code for a function that reads an image from specified path, draws the image, waits for any input to close a window and returns the image object.

```
import cv2

def cv2_imshow(path, title):
    """
    function:
    - reads image from `path`,
    - shows image in a separate window,
    - waits for any key to close the window.

    return: image object
    """

    img = cv2.imread(path)

    cv2.startWindowThread()
    cv2.imshow(title, img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
    
    return img
```

Call the function with image path and title:

```
img_raw = cv2_imshow(path = r'img\example\test.png', title = "raw image")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just developed a library to facilitate the opencv functionality in Jupyter.
I used buttons in jupyter for simulating waitKey
It shows the image in the jupyer.
[Document](https://github.com/modaresimr/opencv_jupyter_ui)

## Installation

```
pip install opencv_jupyter_ui
```

## Usage

You need to only change cv2 to jcv2.

```
import opencv_jupyter_ui as jcv2
...
jcv2.imshow(img,title)
if jcv2.waitKey(1000)==ord('q'):
    break

jcv2.destroyAllWindows()
```