# opencv keeps ignoring my cv2.waitkey(1) character

Tags: python, json, opencv

I'm using opencv's waitkey(1) and saved it in a variable named 'key'
why does my program keep on ignoring my character?
Code:

```
CAMERA = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
camera_height = 500

raw_frames_type_1 = []
raw_frames_type_2 = []
raw_frames_type_3 = []
raw_frames_type_4 = []

while CAMERA.isOpened():

    #Read a new camera frame
    ret, frame = CAMERA.read()

    #Flip
    frame = cv2.flip(frame, 1)

    #Rescale the images output
    aspect = frame.shape[1] / float(frame.shape[0]) 
    res = int(aspect* camera_height)
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (res, camera_height))

    #The green rectable
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (300, 75), (650, 425), (0,255,0), 2)
    
    #Show the Frame
    cv2.imshow("Capturing", frame)

    #Controls q = quit/ s = capturing 
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if key & 0xff == ('q'):
        break

    elif key & 0xFF == ord('1'):
        #Save the raw frames to frame 
        raw_frames_type_1.append(frame)

    elif key & 0xFF== ord('2'):
        #Save the raw frames to frame
        raw_frames_type_2.append(frame)

    elif key & 0xFF== ord('3'):
        #Save the raw frames to frame
        raw_frames_type_3.append(frame)

    elif key & 0xFF == ord('4'):
        #Save the raw frames to frame 
        raw_frames_type_4.append(frame)
        
    #preview
    plt.imshow(frame)
    plt.show()

#Camera
CAMERA.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I tried re installing opencv altogether, but the problem still persists. I think its got something to do with my settings or json file?

Comment: An opencv window must have mouse focus. Is that the case in your setup, or are you "working" in a non-opencv window?

Comment: Hi @Micka ! I'm using jupyter notebook if that's your question, hope you can help me ;)

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/32861853/2393191 and the other answers